# How do I uncompress a file and read it to the ByteBuffer in java?

Tags: java, android, stream, gzip, bytebuffer

I have a piece of code like so...

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filein);
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fi);
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(115200);
```

The `fi.available()` is 84300, but the `gzis.available()` is only 1. The `file(filein)` is already compressed.

I want to read the file, uncompress it, and finally put it into my `ByteBuffer bbufer`.

How could I realize this operation?

Comment: *"THX 4"*  Thanks in future for spelling all letters of words like 'thanks' and 'for'.  This is a technical site, not a text message or Twitter.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gzis.available() = 1;` doesn't mean that there is a problem, it simply means that you can only read 1 byte of information from the Stream before you can continue. you can't expect that the entire uncompressed file will be available in a single command.

To read the entire file, you will need to have a loop that continues to read over the InputStream until you have all the data. For example...

```
int bytesRead = 0;
int bytesAvailable = gzis.available();
while (bytesAvailable > 0){
    gzis.read(bbuffer,bytesRead,bytesAvailable);
    bytesRead += bytesAvailable;
    bytesAvailable = gzis.available();
}
```

Of course, if you aren't sure of the final size of the uncompressed file, you'll need to add in extra code to allow your `bbuffer` to be resized if you need more room.

Comment: BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out)),1024 * 8);
bos.write(buffer.array());                                                So, bro , when I compress a file like this, is that right?

Comment: Not sure about the `buffer.array()` bit - that depends on what ***buffer*** is. If its `byte[] buffer` then you just need to call `bos.write(buffer);` You also probably don't need the `BufferedOutputStream`, as `GZIPOutputStream` already contains a buffer. However, it doesn't hurt to leave the `BufferedOutputStream` there if you want.